# SQL Import data from Azure using SSMS Import/Export Wizard

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have created a local database and now I am trying to import data from my azure database using SSMS Import/Export wizard. It worked fine and data is imported. The issue is the primary key is auto-generated during the import process and is different from the remote database due to which I am facing some issues when I try to run my code. For example. I have two tables Customers and Products. The Primary key ID in my remote customer table starts from 5. So, the id of the second customer is 6. But now since the second customer's ID is 2 in my local DB and my foreign key is still 6 in the Product table. It points to a different customer now. **Is there a way to import data as it is from remote DB, even the primary key or is there another way to do this.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood that I wanted the exact copy of the database and this cannot be achieved using the Import/Export wizard as it generates the Primary keys during the import process. The database becomes unusable if you have deleted some rows on the server etc. In this case, I created a bacpac file using the [SqlBackupandftp tool](https://sqlbackupandftp.com/Azure-SQL-Database-backup/). Then, created the database locally using the bacpac file. [SSMS -> right click on the **Databases** folder -> Import Data-Tier application -> Choose the bacpac file. This will copy the database as such.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tool, it may help you to import the data successfully
https://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/

Comment: Your link is about migrate to Azure SQL Database. The question is to import data from Azure.

Comment: you can use it in both way based on the source and destination information

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server Import and Export Wizard, after Copy data from on or more tables or views, you select source tables, OPEN Edit Mapping... check Enable identity insert.

Comment: Can you create a temporary set of destination tables without PK/FK? Import the data to there, see if they have exactly the same data as the source. Then to figure out to insert into your real final tables.